# jQuery ajax call get API that returns Task<ActionResult<List<ApiObject>>> keeps getting 500 error response

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-webapi

HTML:

```
<div id="api-calls" class="ui-drop-shadow">
    <button id="ajax" class="form-control">ajax call</button>
</div>
```

jQuery call is as below:

```
on(ajax, "click", function(event) { 
          alert('ajax');
           $.ajax({ 
               type: "GET",
               data: {SiteId: 8},
               dataType: "json",
               //dataType: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
               //dataType: "jsonp",
               //url: "https://localhost:44310/api/site/search?SiteId=8",
               url: "https://localhost:44310/api/site/search",
               success: function(data){        
                  alert(data);
               }
           });
        });
```

ASP.NET SiteController:

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<ApiObject>>> Search(int? SiteId)
{
 //Database logics that get to the 'recList' record list... all worked

 // finally, construct a list of the ApiObject for return, this is where the call failed
 // every time.
 recAPIList = recList.Select(a => new ApiObject()
            {
                ApiObjectId = a.ObjectId,
                Description = a.Description,
                Name = a.Name,
                IsDisabled = a.IsDisabled,
            })
            .ToList();

            return Ok(recAPIList);
}
```

as you can see, I've tried all kinds of combination of `dataType` in the ajax call, but all of then keeps failing at the final step in the ASP.NET controller that construct a list of return APIObjects.

The network response upon inspection gave the following error:

```
{"Type":null,"Title":"An unexpected error occurred!","Status":500,
"Detail":"The Instance value should be used to identify the problem when contacting support.\r\n
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element\r\n   
at System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowMoreThanOneElementException()\r\n   
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   
at Controllers.SiteController.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Search>b__7(Site a) 
in \\Controllers\\SiteController.cs:line 167\r\n   
at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectListIterator`2.ToList()\r\n   
at lambda_method(Closure , Object )\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)","Instance":"urn:nebraskadss:error:5eae0ea1-af8a-4cb9-9532-2060c922af93","Extensions":{}}
```

I also tried in the controller to replace that `.ToList() Linq` statement with a for loop to create the list of ApiObjects, still fail with the same error response.

I want to add that this endpoint is from an existing working application that has asp.net core back end and angular front end and it is meant to retrieve a list of objects. The only reason I am posting this question is because this exception only happens when I call it from jQuery!

Comment: Can you show  where your reclist from? Is this anonymos object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read carefully:

> Sequence contains more than one element

and

> at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single

This means that you are doing `.Single()` on a Collection or Enumerable object, which is allowed, but then that Collection or Enumerable object produces *2 or more items*.

`Single()` forces 1 result. If it finds 0 results, or 2 or more results, then it throws an error. You either need to fix the collection, or if that is not possible, consider using `First()` instead of `Single()`.

Finally, it also looks like the error is caused by code that you are not showing. If `recList` is the result of a query, then you need to fix that query.

Comment: this exception only happens when it is called from jQuery, it has been working in our Angular app.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the ajax request

```
            $.ajax({     
               url: "https://localhost:44310/api/site/search?siteId=8",
               type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data){        
                  alert( JSON.stringify(data));
               }
```

or keep the ajax but change the action header

```
[HttpGet("~/api/site/search/{siteId?}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<ApiObject>>> Search(int? siteId)
```